# How can I get return value from a web-service with django/python

Tags: python, django, web-services, post, httprequest

I am posting some parameters to a web-service as follows:

`requests.post("http://**.***.**.**:****/MyLogin/services/DBConnection/callLoginProcedure?inputPhoneNumber=" + phone + "&inputPassword=" + password)`

The "callLoginProcedure" returns an integer value but I couldn't manage to get that value. How can I get this return value?

**views.py:**

```
def index(request):
    post = request.POST.copy()
    if post.get('login_button'):
        phone = post.get('phone_num')
        password = post.get('password')



        requests.post("http://**.***.**.**:****/MyLogin/services/DBConnection/callLoginProcedure?                                                   
            inputPhoneNumber=" + phone + "&inputPassword=" + password)
        r = request.GET.get("return", "-1")
        # if r == 1:
        #     messages.info(request, 'successful!')
        # else:
        #     messages.info(request, 'unsuccessful!')
        messages.info(request, r)
    return render(request, 'login/index.html')
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
path(r'^$', views.index, name = 'script'),
```

]

**Edit:**

My problem is solved but I get proxy error when requests.post function is called. I don't know how to solve it. The stacktrace is as follows:

```
    Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/login/

Django Version: 2.2.3
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['login',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py" in urlopen
  603.                                                   chunked=chunked)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py" in _make_request
  344.             self._validate_conn(conn)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py" in _validate_conn
  843.             conn.connect()

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py" in connect
  370.             ssl_context=context)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py" in ssl_wrap_socket
  368.     return context.wrap_socket(sock)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py" in wrap_socket
  412.             session=session

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py" in _create
  853.                     self.do_handshake()

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py" in do_handshake
  1117.             self._sslobj.do_handshake()

During handling of the above exception ([SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py" in send
  449.                     timeout=timeout

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py" in urlopen
  641.                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py" in increment
  399.             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))

During handling of the above exception (HTTPSConnectionPool(***): Max retries exceeded with url: **** (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)')))), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\TOLGA\Desktop\PythonWebProjects\WebLogin\login\views.py" in index
  53.         response = requests.post('{}?{}'.format(endpoint, qd.urlencode()))

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py" in post
  116.     return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py" in request
  60.         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py" in request
  533.         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py" in send
  646.         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py" in send
  514.                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)

Exception Type: SSLError at /login/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I strongly suggest that you do *not* encode the URL yourself, but use Django's `QueryDict` for example, like:

```
from django.http import QueryDict

qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
qd.update(inputPhoneNumber=phone, inputPassword=password)
```

For example:

```
>>> qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
>>> qd.update(inputPhoneNumber=phone, inputPassword=password)
>>> qd.urlencode()
'inputPhoneNumber=0015550183&inputPassword=some_password'
```

Next, you should read out the response of the POST request, like:

```
from django.http import QueryDict
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError
import requests
```

endpoint = 'http://68.183.75.84:8080/Calculator/services/DBConnection/callLoginProcedure'

def index(request):
    post = request.POST
    if request.POST.get('login_button'):
        qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
        qd.update(
            inputPhoneNumber=request.POST.get('phone_num'),
            inputPassword=request.POST.get('password')
        )
        **response** = requests.post('{}?{}'.format(endpoint, qd.urlencode()))
        try:
            result = **response.json()**
        else JSONDecodeError:
            result = **-1**
        # ...
    return render(request, 'login/index.html')

Comment: First, thanks for your elegant answer. I have done as you said. However, now I get proxy error: "ProxyError at /login/HTTPConnectionPool" Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Exqra: usually that means that it can not contact the server (for one reason or another). Are you sure no firewall is blocking the request?

Comment: I've disabled firewall, but still get the same error.

Comment: @Exqra: can you make the call manually, for example with `curl`?

Comment: How can I use "curl"? I am new to python

Comment: @Exqra: `curl` is a Linux command: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html Perhaps it is worth to first try to use a tool to check you can make a call, before trying to do this programatically.

Comment: When I open the url on browser with some parameters, I see the xml result on the page. So, I guess I can make the call. But maybe my proxy settings on the project are missing

Comment: @Exqra: it does not print extra information/messages on the traceback? Can you edit the question with the stacktrace?

Comment: @Exqa: are you sure that you can use http here (instead of https)?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I change url as https and the problem solved. But unfortunately, another problem occurred. Now I get SSLError. I edited the post again, stacktrace is there.

Comment: @Exqra: you can use `.post(..., verify=False)`, although that is of course a bit unsafe. It looks like the host with which you are talking has a certificate that is not validated.