# Python-Django [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] Error

Tags: python, django, ssl, https, python-requests

While I'm trying to connect to my localhost, I get [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] error. I'm using '8080' port by default. Previously, I was getting ProxyError, then I changed my url from 'http' to 'https' and now I get SSLError. I've checked some solutions, which prompts to change the port number. Does it have to do anything with the port number, or something else?

**views.py:**

```
endpoint = 'https://****:8080/MyApp/services/DBConnection/callLoginProcedure'

def index(request):
    post = request.POST
    if request.POST.get('login_button'):
        qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
        qd.update(
            inputPhoneNumber=request.POST.get('phone_num'),
            inputPassword=request.POST.get('password')
        )
        response = requests.post('{}?{}'.format(endpoint, qd.urlencode()), verify=False)
        result = response.json()
        messages.info(request, result)

    return render(request, 'login/index.html')
```

**The error is as follows**

**stacktrace:**

```
Django Version: 2.2.3
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['login',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py" in urlopen
  603.                                                   chunked=chunked)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py" in _make_request
  344.             self._validate_conn(conn)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py" in _validate_conn
  843.             conn.connect()

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py" in connect
  370.             ssl_context=context)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py" in ssl_wrap_socket
  368.     return context.wrap_socket(sock)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py" in wrap_socket
  412.             session=session

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py" in _create
  853.                     self.do_handshake()

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py" in do_handshake
  1117.             self._sslobj.do_handshake()

During handling of the above exception ([SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py" in send
  449.                     timeout=timeout

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py" in urlopen
  641.                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py" in increment
  399.             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))

During handling of the above exception (HTTPSConnectionPool(****): Max retries exceeded with url: /MyApp/services/DBConnection/callLoginProcedure?inputPhoneNumber=231412&inputPassword=4211 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)')))), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\TOLGA\Desktop\PythonWebProjects\WebLogin\login\views.py" in index
  53.         response = requests.post('{}?{}'.format(endpoint, qd.urlencode()), verify=False)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py" in post
  116.     return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py" in request
  60.         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py" in request
  533.         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py" in send
  646.         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py" in send
  514.                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)

Exception Type: SSLError at /login/
Exception Value: HTTPSConnectionPool(***) (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)')))
```

Comment: do you have SSL certificate?

Comment: No, how can I have it?

Comment: Otherwise how do you run your `endpoint` with `https`?

Comment: I dont know much about these protocols. How can I add ssl certificate?

Comment: It's okay, just search on Google. You'll find lots of online resources.

Comment: This is the kind of error you get if you connect with `https://` to a server which does only `http://`. Taking your statement of *"Previously, I was getting ProxyError, then I changed my url from 'http' to 'https' and now I get SSLError."* I'm pretty sure that you don't know what you are doing and you just try various things without understanding what they mean. Only, I don't know either what you are doing since you did not describe it (i.e. the actual setup of your server) so I cannot help. In other words: the question lacks essential information to help you which makes it too broad.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich My main problem is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56912470/how-can-i-get-return-value-from-a-web-service-with-django-python/56912552#56912552 I was told to change http to https. It would be a pleasure if you helped me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> endpoint = 'https://****:8080/MyApp/services/DBConnection/callLoginProcedure'
> ```

From the your edits in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56912470/revisions) the original URL can be retrieved. When trying this it is clear that the endpoint you are trying to access only supports HTTP on the given port 8080 and not HTTPS as you are trying to use.

> [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] Error

The error you see stems from the attempt to access a site with HTTPS which only can do HTTP. Your clients starts a TLS handshake by sending a ClientHello and expects the server to reply with a ServerHello. Only, the server sends a plain HTTP response. The client then tries to interpret this response as TLS ServerHello which includes figuring out the TLS protocol version from some bytes at a specific position in the response. Since this is no TLS response is expected the information there make no sense when interpreted as TLS which results in this strange error message.

The proper way is to access the URL by HTTP not HTTPS. If you get problems there (you mention some ProxyError without details) then you need to fix these problems and not just attempt to access the site by HTTPS - which as you see only causes other problems.

Comment: Helpful answer, thanks. Do you have any suggestion to solve this "ProxyError"?

Comment: @Exqra: Either you are using a proxy you should not use or you are using a proxy which is blocking access (common in corporate networks) or maybe something else. Unfortunately, with only `ProxyError` one can not narrow down what exactly the problem is. But hopefully you know more about your working environment and can decide which of the possible causes I gave might be the likely one.